# compiling CUDA code to binary inside C++ file in VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda

I'm working to produce a plugin for a 3d application , this plugin uses that application SDK

in normal cases "personal test projects" , I separate .cu file and make its item type to CUDA C/C++ , and .cpp file to item type C/C++ compiler

here I want the whole code inside .cpp file and compile it without problems,

also I want to make the code (binary) so that I can hide the ptx (or kernels)

Comment: You need `.cu` extension to make the compiler driver `nvcc` intercept the CUDA code. When you compile by Visual Studio, you will get an executable in the Debug or Release directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear why you want to put CUDA code in a .cpp file.  If the reason is due to some requirements of the SDK you are using, and you don't want to use `nvcc`, that won't work.

If you simply want to allow a .cpp file to contain device code and go through `nvcc` instead of directly to the host compiler, you can use the `-x cu` option on your `nvcc` compile command:

```
nvcc -x cu t264.cpp -o t264
```

The above command will generate the same executable just as if you had done this:

```
nvcc t264.cu -o t264
```

(assuming `t264.cu` and `t264.cpp` were identical files.)

If you want to strip out the ptx, you can compile like this:

```
nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_10,code=sm_10 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 ....
```

This will tell [nvcc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation) to create a fatbinary that contains executable binaries for sm_10, sm_20, or sm_30 devices, but no PTX.